# Optimizations with UpdateTimestampsCache

Tags: c#, optimization, nhibernate, profiling

I use NHibernate 3.4.1.400 and the profiler shows its `UpdateTimestampsCache` methods at the top.

It's mostly called from `Commit` in updating requests but sometimes in select-only requests too.

Is there anything I can do to reduce calls to that part?

[image: Profiler]

Comment: btw don't use log4net, it's very slow. I will migrate to NLog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using second level query caching, you can disable this completely with the following configuration:

```
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
```

More information is available in [the documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-querycache)

Comment: I don't use second level caching for this specific cache region. I'll consider using separate session factories.